# Robolectric - exceptions in fake http layer

Tags: android, http, robolectric

I know how to fake different HTTP responses in Robolectric but cannot find out how to fake that a certain exception was thrown. Anyone knows how to do this?

Edit: My app shows an alert dialog when some different exceptions are thrown during a HTTP request (Timeout, IO etc). In Robolectric I want to fake this in order to verify that my alert dialog is shown.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question a bit? :)